# What is the correct GCP user role that I should assign to my external website developer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

Hi Google Cloud Platform (GCP) experts!

I am in the process of developing my own website. My external website developer has requested an access to GCP to use the Translation API for language localization and for other things like Google Sign in & Sign up,...etc.

Now, I have created the organization with domain registration. However, I am not sure what is the most secure way to ensure that the developer can develop the projects with the APIs needed without having too many permissions or being able to see the billing data.

Please advise what will be the best permissions/role/user to be assigned to my website developer?

Thank you and best regards,
Ali

Answer (score 1):

Following [Google Best practices for role recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/recommender-best-practices), you should grant the minimum role level to execute the work. If your developer only need access to the Translation API, you can grant his account with this role: Cloud Translation API Editor.

If you want him to have full access to the Cloud Translation resources, you can gran him the Cloud Translation API Admin.

In case you have more than one developer and they all need the same permissions, you can create an [IAM group](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_group), add the developer's mails to the group and assign the necessary roles to it.

You can read more about roles here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles.

Answer (score 1):

There are many strategies to implement. I will recommend one.

**Step 1: Project Separation**

Create a separate project for the website developer. His development work should be published in that project. Once tested and validated release to the **production** project. See Step 4 below for implementing source code control and CI/CD.

Create a separate DNS zone for the developer. An example might be **dev.example.com**. Depending on the Google Cloud service that you are using, such as Compute Engine, you can lock down access to the endpoint with VPC Firewall rules so that only specific IP addresses can access the development website. Customer will not be able to see work in progress.

**Step 2: OAuth Client ID**

To grant the ability to create OAuth Client IDs requires several permissions. I recommend creating a custom role with these permissions. Attach the custom role to the developer's identity.

- clientauthconfig.clients.create
- clientauthconfig.clients.createSecret
- clientauthconfig.clients.delete
- clientauthconfig.clients.get
- clientauthconfig.clients.getWithSecret
- clientauthconfig.clients.list
- clientauthconfig.clients.listWithSecrets
- clientauthconfig.clients.undelete
- clientauthconfig.clients.update

Another option, which is more secure, is to create the OAuth Client ID yourself and provide the developer with the Client ID and Client Secret.

**Step 3: Translation APIs**

You have several options. I recommend granting the Cloud Translation API Editor role to the developer.

[Translation IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/intro-to-v3#iam)

**Step 4: Source Code Repository and CI/CD**

I recommend that you create a GitHub repository, put the project under source code control. Implement GitHub Actions to automatically build, test and deploy code releases. Grant the developer the ability to push updates to the repository. GitHub Actions Workflows would automatically build, test and deploy the code to the developer project. The best option is to create a GitHub Organization account so that you have extended user management.